# Nested IF Statement with multiple values to same output

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I would like to find a method to create an `IF` statement where values in GMS's all equal to the given value in column "Range"

```
IF((B2=441, B2>=443, B2<=448), B2=450, B2 = 451), "A", IF(....
```

I know the above is very incorrect, but looking for any leads on how to work this through.

[image: Values]

Answer (score 0):

### TEXTJOIN with IF or IFS

The [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) function combines the values from multiple ranges and/or strings and is the key to combining the column values into a single cell.  To determine *which* column to [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) using the values in the column labeled "Range" you *can* use IF or IFS however they will make the formula more difficult to maintain should you wish to add, remove, or change columns in the future.

```
# IF

=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, 
   IF(G2="A", A:A, IF(G2="B", B:B,
     IF(G2="C", C:C, IF(G2="D", D:D, "")))))

# IFS

=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, 
   IFS(G2="A", A:A, G2="B", B:B,
       G2="C", C:C, G2="D", D:D, TRUE, ""))
```

### TEXTJOIN with INDEX and CODE

Another approach uses the [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd) function to return a single column from a range of columns. [CODE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/code-function-c32b692b-2ed0-4a04-bdd9-75640144b928) is used to determine the column number to [INDEX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/index-function-a5dcf0dd-996d-40a4-a822-b56b061328bd). It returns the numeric code for the character in "Range" which is always `64` greater than the column number associated with that same letter.  The formula will work for any Columns from A to Z. To include columns above Z the formula gets much more complex.

```
# Columns <= Z

=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, 
   INDEX(A:Z,,CODE(UPPER(G2))-64))

# Columns > Z 
# Example is  A:ALL (1,000 columns)

=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, INDEX(A:ALL,,
   SUM((CODE(MID(G2,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(G2)),1))-64)*
     TRANSPOSE(FILTER({676;26;1}, SEQUENCE(3)>3-LEN(G2))))))
```

[image]

### TEXTJOIN with INDIRECT

[INDIRECT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) returns the reference specified by a text string. This works for any column regardless if it is **A** or **XFD**.  It is also case insensitive.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ", TRUE, INDIRECT(G2&":"&G2))
```

[image]

| Formula | Equivalent Formula | Returned |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `=G2` | `="A"` | String: **A** |
| `=G2&":"&G2` | `="A:A"` | String: **A:A** |
| `=INDIRECT(G2&":"&G2)` | `=INDIRECT("A:A")` | Array: **Column A** |